# Sorting a Map with JSON data as values

Tags: java, json, sorting, collections, treemap

```
{"5eaa9ce8": {
            "Id": "1958208",
            "priority": 0
             },
"5eaa9bs8": {
            "Id": "1958208",
            "priority": 2
             },
"6eaa9ce8": {
            "Id": "1958208",
            "priority": 1
             }
}
```

Need to sort this Map based on the priority of the key.

and needed output is
{
"5eaa9bs8": {
                "Id": "1958208",
                "priority": 2
                 },
"6eaa9ce8": {
                "Id": "1958208",
                "priority": 1
                 },
"5eaa9ce8": {
                "Id": "1958208",
                "priority": 0
                 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Json objects won't maintain order, to preserve order use Arrays

step 1: convert your Object to array:

```
keys = Object.keys(yourObj)
for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
   yourArr.push(keys[i])
}
```

step 2: sort your array:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  aKey = Object.keys(a)[0];
  bKey = Object.keys(b)[0];
  if (a[akey].priority < b[bKey].priority)
    return -1;
  if (a[aKey].priority > b[bKey].priority )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
yourArr.sort(compare)
```

hope this helps!!